# How to check a character of a UnicodeString?

Tags: c++, c++builder

How to check a character of a UnicodeString?

I tried:

```
UnicodeString us = "stuff";
if ( (us[2] == L"@") )
```

but I get: `E2034 Cannot convert 'wchar_t &' to 'const wchar_t *'`.

I also tried:

```
us.FirstChar ()
```

will return the whole string instead of the first char. Details here: [Why str.FirstChar() does not return the first char? [C++ Builder]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758114/why-str-firstchar-does-not-return-the-first-char)

Comment: what type is us ?

Comment: us is UnicodeString (according to the Hungarian notation :) )

Comment: Does if (us[1].c_str() == L"@") work ?

Comment: No. I get E2294 Structure required on left side of . or .*

Comment: which platform are you using?

Comment: C++ builder, Win32

Comment: In windows you can use MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte API functions for conversion to normal string.

Comment: @P.W - yes. and this is the reason of the decline: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a single Unicode character to a Unicode string literal.

Try this instead:

```
if ( us[2] == L'@' )
```

Note the single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Everybody_hates_BillTheLizard Single quotes?